# Guava concurrency tutorials/code

Tags: java, concurrency, guava

Is there any example code that shows guava collection features (e.g. Futures, ValueFuture and ListenableFutureTask) ?

Comment: They're essentially just convenience wrappers/adapters around the existing `java.util.concurrent.Future` class, I don't think they really enable anything exciting *per se*.  It's more a matter of doing in one line what would otherwise take five lines and an anonymous inner class.

Comment: My need to execute a set of Future Tasks and combine all the responses from the result of the tasks. Is there anyway to do this by chaining Future Tasks with functions? P.S. my tasks are blocking tasks.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at [guava explained](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/GuavaExplained) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The definitive source of knowledge when using java.util.concurrent classes (and thus the Guava concurrent features that are just further implementations and convenience wrappers) is the book [Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/).

If I had two Java book recommendations to make, it would be "Effective Java" and "Concurrency in Practice".